# Database Normalization (3NF) - Foreign keys

Tags: database, database-normalization

After trying to understand the 3NF, I've come into a little issue that I am not sure I understand correctly.

The problem occurs in a structural component as follows:

```
s = {
Product(ProductID, ProductName, ProductDescription, SupplierName, SupplierAddress, SupplierID)
}

F = {
ProductID -> ProductName, ProductDescription
SupplierID -> SupplierName, SupplierAddress
}
```

Of course, by default, I'll move both the SupplierName and SupplierAddress to a different entity / table. The issue comes to in the form of SupplierID. I don't know if it is okay to keep the SupplierID in the Product table / entity.

The thing is, SupplierID doesn't depend on the ProductID (as it's written within F). I believe that putting it into a 3rd table (as follows) would be fine.

```
S = {
  Products(ProductID, ProductName, ProductDescription),
  Suppliers(SupplierID, SupplierName, SupplierAddress),
  PS(ProductID, SupplierID)
}
```

However, would the 3NF be still ok if I had put SupplierID within the Products table (not have the "PS" table at all).

Comment: Hi. You should be following a reference including an algorithm to decompose to 3NF preserving FDs. You also write as though you're not and as though you don't know how to apply the definition of 3NF. What is your 3NF/normalzation reference? Because an explanation of what you should be doing is just a rewrite of such a reference. Explain how you have followed it and where you are stuck. If you don't follow a reference what good is a piecemeal description of how some thing you came up with under misconceptions is wrong, in terms of a bunch of notions you don't understand?

Comment: What does this have to do with FKs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decomposition in three relations is correctly in 3NF, while if you put SupplierID in the Product table you obtain a relation which is not even in 2NF.

In fact, in a relation:

```
R1(ProductDescription, ProductID, ProductName, SupplierID)
```

since the two following two dependencies hold:

```
 ProductID → ProductName
 ProductID → ProductDescription
```

the (only) candidate key of the relation is (ProductID, SupplierID). This means that the two previous dependencies violate the 3NF, since the left side is not a superkey and the right hand side is a non prime attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: My apologies. I wanted to quickly confirm that if the case were that SupplierID depends on ProductID (`ProductID → SupplierID`) while it still remains a foreign key, it'd be fine to include it in the `Products` table?

Comment: @Superstar, in that case, a correct decomposition in Third Normal Form is constituted only by the  two tables, `R1(ProductDescription ProductID ProductName SupplierID)` and `R2(SupplierAddress SupplierID SupplierName)`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and for the help.

Comment: @Superstar FKs have nothing to do with normalization. Components are projections of an original. So for any two tables among an original & its components, for any set of attribute(s) in both there is a FK both ways. Your interest in FKs is confused & your statements/questions about them don't make sense. (Do you maybe mean FD? A foreign key is not a functional dependency.) Most of your phrasing doesn't make sense. Eg notice how this answer & its comments just address normalization based on some basic info you give but not your specific (misconceived) questions/processes.